# Can I set google translate automatically to a particular language

Tags: javascript, arabic, google-translate, translate, google-translation-api

I have a code for google translation. All I want is to automatically translate a page(which is in english) into arabic on clicking a button. Is there any possibility to achieve this.

`

function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement(
'google_translate_element')
}`